# In titanium how to take a screenshot of full scrollview?

Tags: ios, titanium, titanium-mobile

I am developing for IOS using Titanium Appcelerator

I want to take screenshot of a full scrollview which is taller than the screen

the following code will take a screen shot of only the visible UI on the device

```
Ti.Media.takeScreenshot(function(e){
    Ti.Media.saveToPhotoGallery(e.media);
});
```

my question is how take a screen shot for the whole scrollview

best regards

Answer (score 4):

this was easy! you can do that by simply calling toImage method

```
     Ti.Media.saveToPhotoGallery(myView.toImage());
```

**note: myView is a child element of myScrollView**

I have got the the answer from **Hakim Messaoud** http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/144683/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-full-scrollview#comment-146883

Answer (score 2):

You can also do something like :

```
Ti.Media.takeScreenshot(function(e) {
    scrollView.toBlob();
    Ti.Media.saveToPhotoGallery(e.media);
});
```